# How to exclude packages from Findbug analysis in maven project in CI?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, continuous-integration, findbugs

We have this configuration in pom.xml:

```
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludeFilterFile>../findbugsExclude.xml</excludeFilterFile>
        ...
```

and in the `findbugsExclude.xml`, we have `Match` tags for exclusions, and this works in Eclipse. But when I raise Git PR, the pull request builder job in CI gets triggered and it reports these excluded packages also. The goal in CI is:

```
findbugs:findbugs
```

and I dont want to change this existing config. How can I exclude the packages that I want? Most of them have autogenerated code.

Comment: Have you tried to change ../findbugsExclude.xml to a value without .. ?

Comment: I rechecked, it does not works properly in local also. Same question I have for PMD also. I just want to exclude some packages, any rule. Not finding an appropriate solution.